# Retain/Release of a Synthesized Setter for a Retained Property

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties

Does the setter of a retained object automatically release the object first?

I am still working without ARC, thus I have these questions.

Suppose I have an ivar defined this way:

```
ObjectClass *anObject_;
```

With propety

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ObjectClass *anObject;
```

And synthesis using

```
@synthesize anObject = anObject_;
```

If I have a setter that is automatically synthesized using the retain attribute, will the setter perform a release first, if it is needed **?** Like this:

```
- (void) setAnObject:(ObjectClass*)anObject {
    if (anObject_) [anObject_ release];
    anObject_ = [anObject retain];
}
```

And can a simply make assignments to the object without first releasing it **?**

Can I release the object by assigning the property to nil **?** (This might be unsafe if there are other owners.)

```
self.anObject = nil;
```

In other words, can I dispense with the `if (anObject_) [anObject_ release];` code outside of the setter and let the synthesized setter do this for me **?**

If I write my own setter, do I need to add/include the retain **?** If a synthesized setter includes the release (which is my initial question), do I need to add/include this, in my own setter **?**

One last thing -- When using ARC, I assume `self.anObject = nil;` and `self.anObject = anthingelse;` are both safe **?** And the original object will be released regardless of what my setter code is **?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to pretty much every single one of your questions is yes. Retains and releases will be added to your code to make it right. Specifically, a setter for a `strong` property will release its current value and retain its new value. Even if you don't use the synthesized accessors and write your own, they'll still have the right behavior. Indeed, under ARC you're not even allowed to call `retain` or `release` in your own code.

The one point you seem a bit confused on is the following:

> Can I release the object by assigning the property to nil ? (This
>   might be unsafe if there are other owners.)

It's true that when you set the property to nil, `release` will be called on the object. But remember, that doesn't necessarily mean the object will be deallocated: that only happens if the retain count goes to 0.

When we say an object **owns** another object, we usually mean that the object has a strong reference to the other object, so that `retain` is called upon assignment. As long as the object has at least one other owner at this point, setting the property to `nil` won't cause it to be deallocated.

There's a much easier way to think about all this if you're using ARC. Forget about `retain` and `release`, and just think of object ownership. An object will not be deallocated as long as some other object owns it (with a `strong` reference). And really the only pitfall to keep in mind are cycles: if two objects own each other, then they can't get deallocated.

Comment: If I understand correctly then, I can set retained property values to nil (or any other value), and this will always release first And this is true even when I have written the setter that does explicity include the `if (anObject_) [anObject_ release];` code. Can you confirm this?

Comment: If you write a setter, and then set its property to `nil`, then `release` will be called on the old object value, even if you didn't call `release` in the setter you wrote. Indeed, you're not **allowed** to call `release` in your setter (or anywhere else) when you're using ARC.